# From list of dictionaries of dictionary to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries of dictionary in python like the example below:

```
{'AU37172316199': {'B25J9/18__2016': 1}},
 {'AU41504932409': {'G06F15/00__2003': 1}},
 {'AU41687119230': {'C07K14/435__1997': 1}},
 {'AU48692741449': {'G06F15/00__2002': 1}},
 {'AU632317250': {'G16H50/00__2021': 1}},
 {'AU68078335009': {'G06F19/00__2009': 1}},
 {'BE0684625505': {'G06Q10/04__2020': 1}},
 {'BM24983R': {'G06Q50/00__2006': 1, 'G16H30/20__2007': 1}},
 {'BO00225660': {'G06V40/10__2022': 1}},
 {'BR02016440000162': {'G01R21/00__2019': 1}},
 {'BR02641663000110': {'G01R21/00__2019': 1}},
 {'BR05706282000160': {'G06F15/00__2004': 1,
   'G06F15/00__2005': 1,
   'G06F15/00__2006': 1,
   'G06F3/00__2005': 1,
   'G06K15/00__2005': 1,
   'H04N1/60__2006': 1}},
 {'BR33121512000165': {'G01R31/28__2020': 1}},
 {'CA132631008L': {'B62D1/24__2003': 1}},
 {'CA203540316L': {'H04L__2018': 1,
   'H04L25/02__2016': 1,
   'H04L25/02__2017': 1,
   'H04W24/00__2016': 1}}
```

I would like to transform it in a dataframe like this (source of data before elaborations).

```
Company result  Flag
0   AE0000392297    G06F17/10__2020 0
1   AT9030014397    B81B7/00__2016  0
2   AT9030014397    B81B7/00__2017  0
3   AU010653844 A01K67/02__2021 0
4   AU010653844 G06K9/62__2021  0
... ... ... ...
18829   ZM119870015693  G10L21/0208__2020   0
18830   ZM119870015693  G10L25/60__2022 0
18831   ZM119870015693  H04N19/117__2022    0
18832   ZM119870015693  H04N21/6587__2022   0
18833   ZM119980040172  G05B13/04__2020 0
```

In addition I would like to put the number values of dictionary (0 or 1) as a new column of the dataframe. The key of the main dictionary would be duplicated as the number of keys in the inner dictionary.

Comment: You need to post a sample of your actual or mock data, not an image.

Comment: I can't see what the rule is that relates the input to the desired output, nor can I see what the *exact* desired output is for this input (the values shown in each are both completely different). Also, we expect textual input and specified textual output [as text, not images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the work:

```
import pandas as pd
df = (
    pd.DataFrame(data) # convert to dataframe
    .T # transpose to get the patent numbers as columns
    .reset_index() # take it out of index
    .melt(id_vars='index') # stack the variables
    .dropna() # remove the nans
    )


df["values"] = df["value"].apply(lambda x: list(zip(x.keys(),x.values()))) # get the codes

df = df.explode("values") # explode the codes (if there are multiple ones)

df = df.drop(columns=["variable","value"]) # drop the unnecessary variable column

df["code"] = df["values"].apply(lambda x: x[0]) # get the code
df["value"] = df["values"].apply(lambda x: x[1]) # get the value

df = df.drop(columns=["values"]) # drop the unnecessary values column
```

Comment: this solution works but I have no evidence of zeros and ones (values of the inner dictionary)

Answer (score 0):

```
    import pandas as pd
    # Flatten the data
    flattened_data = []
    for item in data:
        for company, results in item.items():
            for result, flag in results.items():
                flattened_data.append({'Company' : company, 'Result' : result, 'Flag' : flag})

    # Create a DataFrame from the flattened data
    df = pd.DataFrame(flattened_data)

    # Print the resulting DataFrame
    print(df)
```

Above code will create a DataFrame with three columns: Company, Result, and Flag. The Company column contains the keys from the main dictionary, the Result column contains the keys from the inner dictionary, and the Flag column contains the values from the inner dictionary.